# How can i use MATCH and AGAINST with db_select?

Tags: 7, database

I have a query like:

```
$query = db_query("
    SELECT *, MATCH(field1,field2) AGAINST ('$s' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance 
    FROM {my_table} 
    ORDER BY Relevance DESC, created DESC
    ");
```

That is working well with db_query.
How can i use same query with db_select function for drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an expression should work:

```
 $query = db_select('foo');
 ...
 $expression = 'MATCH(field1,field2) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
 $query->addExpression($expression, 'Relevance', [':search' => '$s']);
 ...
```

See [`SelectQuery::addExpression`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x) for more info.